# How the Dimensions of an object would change with respect to Distance

Tags: geometry

Lets say a rectangular object has 100 x 200 cm dimensions. Suppose I need to draw an image(Parallel View) of the object from 25cm away. The apparent size of the object obviously gets reduced.

Referred Links:

http://www.giantitp.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-294360.html

[Calculating size of an object based on distance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/859760/calculating-size-of-an-object-based-on-distance)

According to the above links, 
The Apparent Length = Original Length/25?? 
Or any other parameters influence the dimensions?

Comment: As far as I know, the apparent size of an object scales inversely with the distance, i.e. twice distance means half the apparent size, and there are no other factors (assuming laboratory conditions)

Comment: The distance is relevant for calculating the changes in ratio and the field of view and the display.

Comment: Yes, the distance is relevant. But how does it effect? With Apparent Length become  4cm when moved 25cm away?